# How can I use assumptions with FindRoot?

Tags: equation-solving, assumptions

I have something like

```
FindRoot[f[x], {x, a}]
```

Now I want `FindRoot` to constrain the solutions to 0 < x < 1. How can I obtain this?

Comment: The easiest (and probably not the fastest) way for you might be to `Select` the solutions given by `FindRoot`.

Comment: Maybe something like `Cases[FindRoot[...],Rule[_,_>0]..&&Rule[_,_<1]..` (I'm not sure whether the `pattern` is the best to filter solutions).

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I would call these constraints, not assumptions.

From the docs,

> FindRoot[lhs==rhs,{$x$, $x_{\text{start}}$, $x_{\text{min}}$, $x_{\text{max}}$}] searches for a solution, stopping the search
>   if x ever gets outside the range $x_{\text{min}}$ to $x_{\text{max}}$

Keep in mind that `FindRoot` uses iterative numerical methods such as Newton's method or Brent's method which will converge to a single solution, but will not find *all* solutions.  What this syntax does is simply stop the iteration as soon as $x$ gets outside of the specified range.  If this happens, it does not mean that there are no solutions inside that range.

Here's a concrete example where there are several roots, but the search stops as soon as the method reached the edge of the search region:

```
In[2]:= FindRoot[Sin[x], {x, 1, .1, 10}]

During evaluation of In[2]:= FindRoot::reged: The point {0.1} is at the edge of the
   search region {0.1,10.} in coordinate 1 and the computed search direction points 
   outside the region. >>

Out[2]= {x -> 0.1}
```

---

If you need to find all roots inside an interval, I'd recommend using `Reduce` [which will often work (if using Mathematica 7 or later)](http://blog.wolfram.com/2008/12/18/mathematica-7-johannes-kepler-and-transcendental-roots/).  Note that while `Reduce` may not be able to find solution for the general case, it will very often work if you restrict the search domain to a real interval.  Even for hard problems with transcendental functions.

Comment: Although if I stick with my `f[x_]:=Sin[x*10]` and if I use `FindRoot[f[x] == 0, {x, 0, 0, 1}]` the only answer it gives is `0.`. Any clue why?

Comment: @Öskå I explained that in this answer.  FindRoot always returns only a single answer (for a single initial condition).

Comment: @Szabolcs Thanks. But now I remain with the problem that the function returns the value of the extreme to which the iteration leads. I wish that I'd get no value at all, if there was no root. Obviously, however, I can not a priori exclude extreme values​​, since there may be the case that these are effectively a solution. Any suggestions?

Comment: @Fabrizio You can verify if the result you get is a root or not by substituting it back into the function, and checking if it gives zero.  This will tell you for certain if it is an endpoint of the interval or it's also a root.  But keep in mind that the search stopping at the edge of the interval does not mean that there are no roots within the interval!  It merely means that the numerical method strayed outside the interval.  There may still be roots there it didn't find before jumping outside.

Comment: @Fabrizio I just checked and FindRoot issues a message if it reaches the end.  You can `Check` for this message.

Comment: @Szabolcs Ok. Is this possible to use a similar strategy when I using `FindRoot[{f(x,y),g(x,y)},{x,x0},{y,y0}]` and I want that `x>y`?

Answer (score 8):

If you already know the interval on which you want to find one of your solution, you may use the instruction

```
FindRoot[f[x]==0,{x,xmin,xmax}]
```

Here, Mathematica will use Brent's algorithm (a combination of the bisection and secant methods) restricted to the interval `[xmin,xmax]`.
With the example

```
FindRoot[Sin[x]==0, {x, .1, 10}]
```

where one searches for a solution in `[0.1,10]`, the algorithm does not fail and leads to

```
{x -> 9.42478}
```

As in all finding-roots methods, Mathematica only find one solution (if it exists) on the interval, even if multiple solutions may exist.

Comment: "dichotomy search" - you meant bisection, yes? It actually uses Brent's method, but it is true that bisection is one of the key ingredients of Brent…

Comment: @Guesswhoitis. Yes you are right (see documentation.), I updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: It's actually more like "a combination of the bisection and secant methods with inverse quadratic interpolation", but that's a mouthful to say. Nevertheless, there's a reason why "Algorithms for Minimization Without Derivatives" is a classic book…

Comment: I believe that you need the form {x, x0, xmin, xmax} instead of {x, x0, x1}

Answer (score 3):

Something like that works, more advanced answers should come from others.

```
f[x_] := Sin[x*10]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
Sort@DeleteDuplicates[Select[FindRoot[f[x], {x, Range[0, 1, 0.1]}][[1,2]], (0 <= # < 1)&],
Abs[#2 - #1] < 10^-8 &]
```

Gives:

> {0., 0.314159, 0.628319, 0.942478}

Answer (score 3):

This is one of the simpler ways to do it:

```
Solve[f[x] == 0 && 0 < x && x < 1, x]
```

Specifying conditions within `Solve` or any other function you are using is more efficient than playing `Select` on the results. This way, Mathematica knows where to look for solutions and only finds those within your constraints.

Comment: But I need specifically FindRoot for solve my problem, and this doesn't work in that case.

Comment: And why do you specifically need `FindRoot`?

Comment: because my problem is very hard, it also contains transcendental functions, so Solve doesn't work in this case.

Comment: @Fabrizio `Reduce` will often work for these kinds of problems *if* you also supply an interval.